# Get random numbers in a specific range in java

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: generating random number in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

I want to generate random numbers using

```
java.util.Random(arg);
```

The only problem is, the method can only take one argument, so the number is always between 0 and my argument. Is there a way to generate random numbers between (say) 200 and 500?

Comment: How unclear can it be? You have an upper bound. You want that to be offset by a number. Add that number. Using `+`. Like, say, `x + 200`.

Comment: Did you notice that when you create question SO shows you list of possible similar questions, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range?rq=1) so you can find answers quicker?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);
int random_integer = rand.nextInt(upperbound-lowerbound) + lowerbound;
```

Comment: Great thanks! It works fine, and your answer was by far the most constructive and useful to me :)

Comment: @imulsion Modulo it being wrong, of course; there's no `Random` constructor that returns a random number. All three other answers use the class correctly, in addition to giving an example of addition.

Comment: Besides being wrong, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I just used nextInt() instead; it was still the most constructive answer

Comment: int next = random.nextInt(upper - lower + 1) + lower;

Answer (score 6):

First of, you have to create a Random object, such as:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

And then, if you want an int value, you should use `nextInt`
    int myValue = r.nextInt(max);

Now, if you want that in an interval, simply do:

```
 int myValue = r.nextInt(max-offset)+offset;
```

In your case:

```
 int myValue = r.nextInt(300)+200;
```

You should check out the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand how Random works. It doesn't return an integer, it returns a Random object with the argument being the *seed value* for the PRNG.

```
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
int myRandomValue = 200 + rnd.nextInt(300);
```

Answer (score 1):

The arg you pass to the constructor is the seed, not the bound.

To get a number between 200 and 500, try the following:

```
Random random = new Random(); // or new Random(someSeed);
int value = 200 + random.nextInt(300);
```