# Create Random Int Array giving a lenght and a range of values in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, random, integer

I am trying to program a Java Code in which, given the lenght of an int array and a min and max values it returns an random array values.

I am trying to program it in the most simple way, but I am still not getting how the programming process works.

What I have tried is the following:

```js
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomIntArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(createRandom(10));
    }
    public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
        Random rd = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        int min = 5;
        int max = 99;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rd.nextInt();
            while (array[i] > min) ;
            while (array[i] < max) ;

        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you provided?

Comment: It doesn't return a random array with the lenght I have introduced given a min and max values

Comment: what does it do instead of the intended behaviour?

Comment: It takes way too long for the code to run. I dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
    Random rd = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[n];
    int min = 5;
    int max = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = rd.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
        System.out.print(array[i] +" ");
    }
    return array;
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    createRandom(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have a question regarding your code: what does this bit mean:  array[i] = rd.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;?

Comment: if your min is 5 and your max is 10,Then (max - min + 1) + min gives you 11,means rd.nextInt(11) and give you numbers 0 ≤ number< 11.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `IntStream` to achieve what you want

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = createRandom(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int min = 5;
    int max = 99;
    return IntStream
            .generate(() -> r.nextInt(max - min) + min)
            .limit(n)
            .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we must adjust is the random number generation. It appears you specify a `min` and `max`, so a number must be generated in with these bounds. We can use the [Random.nextInt(int bound) method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to set a range equal to `max - min`. However, this range will start from 0, so we must add your `min` value to make the bound complete. Using this process will eliminate the need for the existing `while` loops. [See this question for more on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743267/get-random-numbers-in-a-specific-range-in-java)

Now, every value in the `array` will be generated as

```
array[i] = rd.nextInt(max - min) + min
```

When trying to print array elements, a System.out.println() statement with the variable name of the array will print a *memory address* of the array. **This will NOT print the entire array of values.**

We must instead iterate over the elements to print them. It would be best to use a for loop to do this, but your program could generate an array of any size. So, we should use a *for-each* loop instead as follows:

```
for (int num : createRandom(10)) { 
   System.out.println(num); 
}
```

This for-each is saying "for each int in the `array` returned by createRandom(10), refer to is as variable `num` and print it."

This is the final code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomIntArray {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      for (int num : createRandom(10)) { 
         System.out.println(num); 
      }
   }
   public static int[] createRandom(int n) {
      Random rd = new Random();
      int[] array = new int[n];
      int min = 5;
      int max = 99;

      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         array[i] = rd.nextInt(max - min) + min;
         System.out.println(array[i]);
      }
      return array;
   }
}
```